# Am I using a semi colon properly here?

Tags: semicolons

Here is the phrase:

"Your choir’s vocal harmony is top notch; now, the time has come for some visual harmony. "

Comment: You have considerable leeway for personal preference in how you punctuate your example sentence, and using a semicolon certainly isn't wrong in this situation. Nevertheless, the two pieces of the sentence are sufficiently independent of each other as ideas that I would be inclined to break them into two sentences, by replacing the semicolon with a period: "Your choir’s vocal harmony is top-notch. Now the time has come for some visual harmony."

Comment: Though I'm usually a fan of short sentences I rather like the use of the semi-colon here. After all, if we don't use colons and semi-colons they may become endangered species. Like the village shop in England, it is a case of 'use it or lose it'!

Comment: @WS2: Surely you meant *ye olde village shoppe*.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification.  It is much appreciated.  Perhaps I can somehow incorporate _italic_ye olde village choir_italic_ here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is entirely acceptable to use a semi-colon to indicate a close relationship between sentences.

In this instance, you could certainly use a period in place of the semi-colon, but the choice of using a semi-colon is a good one: it makes the contrast between the two statements more powerful and surprising by emphasizing the connection of 'harmony'. Bravo.